# Error executing DDL "create table users (...)" via JDBC Statement

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, kotlin, h2

I am trying to learn how to use the H2 database in my Spring Boot application but am running into trouble with respect to creating a table representing the defined entity located in `User.kt`. Seemingly the table creation fails and as such the data insertion from `data.sql` reasonably so also fails. I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

I am not sure if it's relevant or not but I have googled around for a while to try and solve this and came across some comment or two somewhere saying something about "If you are using Spring Security then you need to do some more configuring in order to use H2" but the people didn't go into any further detail. Googling about this has not yielded anything useful for me. I did see some concrete examples that used some kind of class that extended `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` to configure some kind of **HTTP** security thing regarding **CSRF** but that (interface) is now deprecated and I couldn't find any "up to date" example.

I am indeed using **Spring Security** and have yet to actually touch it as I have yet to learn about it, I am focusing on getting up the database first. Do I need to do anything with that in order to make the database work?

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:appdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

**User.kt**

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "users")
open class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    open var id: Long = 1;

    @Column(name = "username'", nullable = false)
    open var username: String = ""

    @Column(name = "pwd", nullable = false)
    open var password: String = ""
}
```

**data.sql**

```sql
INSERT INTO users (username, pwd)
VALUES ('user1', '123'),
    ('user2', '123'),
    ('user3', '123');
```

**Stacktrace**

```
2022-06-21 12:23:41.352  INFO 1780 --- [  restartedMain] com.name.news.app.ApplicationKt     : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-06-21 12:23:41.387  INFO 1780 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2022-06-21 12:23:41.387  INFO 1780 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2022-06-21 12:23:41.750  INFO 1780 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-06-21 12:23:41.780  INFO 1780 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 25 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-06-21 12:23:42.214  INFO 1780 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8082 (http)
2022-06-21 12:23:42.221  INFO 1780 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-06-21 12:23:42.222  INFO 1780 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.63]
2022-06-21 12:23:42.275  INFO 1780 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-06-21 12:23:42.275  INFO 1780 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 887 ms
2022-06-21 12:23:42.297  INFO 1780 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-06-21 12:23:42.424  INFO 1780 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-06-21 12:23:42.431  INFO 1780 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:appdb'
2022-06-21 12:23:42.524  INFO 1780 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-06-21 12:23:42.555  INFO 1780 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.9.Final
2022-06-21 12:23:42.651  INFO 1780 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2022-06-21 12:23:42.714  INFO 1780 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2022-06-21 12:23:43.036  WARN 1780 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "create table users (id bigint not null, pwd varchar(
255) not null, username' varchar(255) not null, primary key (id))" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table users (id bigint not null, pwd varchar(255) not null, username' varchar(255) not null, primary key (id))" via JDBC Statement
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:458) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:442) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.createFromMetadata(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:325) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:169) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:124) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:168) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:335) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1498) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at com.name.news.app.ApplicationKt.main(Application.kt:12) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "create table users (id bigint not null, pwd varchar(255) not null, username[*]' varchar(255) not null, primary key (id))"; SQL statement:
create table users (id bigint not null, pwd varchar(255) not null, username' varchar(255) not null, primary key (id)) [42000-212]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:502) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:477) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:223) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:199) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:247) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
        at org.h2.command.Tokenizer.readCharacterString(Tokenizer.java:1098) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
        at org.h2.command.Tokenizer.tokenize(Tokenizer.java:226) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.initialize(Parser.java:5848) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:657) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:568) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
        at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareLocal(SessionLocal.java:631) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
        at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareCommand(SessionLocal.java:554) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1116) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:237) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:223) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
        ... 39 common frames omitted

2022-06-21 12:23:43.046  INFO 1780 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-06-21 12:23:43.083  INFO 1780 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-06-21 12:23:43.130  WARN 1780 --- [  restartedMain] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly config
ure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2022-06-21 12:23:43.235  INFO 1780 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping    : Adding welcome page template: index
2022-06-21 12:23:43.644  WARN 1780 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationExce
ption: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method faile
d; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/D:/Documents/Programming/news.app/target/classes/data.sql]: INSERT INTO users (u
sername, pwd) VALUES ('user1', '123'), ('user1', '123'), ('user1', '123'); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "users" not found (this database is empty); SQL statement:
INSERT INTO users (username, pwd) VALUES ('user1', '123'), ('user1', '123'), ('user1', '123') [42104-212]
2022-06-21 12:23:43.645  INFO 1780 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-06-21 12:23:43.645  INFO 1780 --- [  restartedMain] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000477: Starting delayed evictData of schema as part of SessionFactory shut-down'
2022-06-21 12:23:43.855  WARN 1780 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor': org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientConnectionE
xception: Database is already closed (to disable automatic closing at VM shutdown, add ";DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE" to the db URL) [90121-212]
2022-06-21 12:23:43.856  INFO 1780 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2022-06-21 12:23:43.857  INFO 1780 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2022-06-21 12:23:43.859  INFO 1780 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-06-21 12:23:43.869  INFO 1780 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-06-21 12:23:43.882 ERROR 1780 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationCon
figuration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/D:/Documents/Programming/news.
app/target/classes/data.sql]: INSERT INTO users (username, pwd) VALUES ('user1', '123'), ('user1', '123'), ('user1', '123'); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "users" not found (this database is empt
y); SQL statement:
INSERT INTO users (username, pwd) VALUES ('user1', '123'), ('user1', '123'), ('user1', '123') [42104-212]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at com.name.news.app.ApplicationKt.main(Application.kt:12) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/D:/Documents/Programming/news.app/target/classes/data.sql]: INSERT INTO users (username, pwd
) VALUES ('user1', '123'), ('user1', '123'), ('user1', '123'); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "users" not found (this database is empty); SQL statement:
INSERT INTO users (username, pwd) VALUES ('user1', '123'), ('user1', '123'), ('user1', '123') [42104-212]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:282) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.populate(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:254) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:54) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.init.DataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.runScripts(DataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:90) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.runScripts(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.applyScripts(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:107) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.applyDataScripts(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:101) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.initializeDatabase(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:76) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:65) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "users" not found (this database is empty); SQL statement:
INSERT INTO users (username, pwd) VALUES ('user1', '123'), ('user1', '123'), ('user1', '123') [42104-212]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:502) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:477) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:223) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:199) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.getTableOrViewNotFoundDbException(Parser.java:8363) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.getTableOrViewNotFoundDbException(Parser.java:8347) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:8336) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:8306) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseInsert(Parser.java:1641) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:814) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:691) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:661) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:568) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
        at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareLocal(SessionLocal.java:631) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
        at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareCommand(SessionLocal.java:554) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1116) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:237) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:223) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:261) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
        ... 33 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `'` from column name:

```
@Column(name = "username'", nullable = false)
```

->

```
@Column(name = "username", nullable = false)
```

`DATABASE_TO_UPPER=FALSE` also looks very suspicious, this setting should normally be used only with H2 1.4.197 and older versions, but this isn't related to your problem.

Comment: Ah, a spelling mistake.. I removed the `'`. I also changed the table name from `users` to `TBL_USERS` and removed the `DATABASE_TO_UPPER=FALSE`. I hade it set to `TRUE` because when doing `INSERT INTO users` was giving erro `could not find table USERS` cause H2 makes all uppercase. **I get no errors now when running the application**. Though now when I navigate to `~/h2-console` and enter the relevant details and press "Connect" I am sent to `/error` and not let into the database. Do you know what can be the reason for this? [Looks like this](https://imgur.com/a/D7Gc5ZC)

Comment: Spring security may need special configuration, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40261302/spring-boot-jpa-h2-console-not-running-application-properties-file-ignored and other questions.

Answer (score 0):

Remove or comment the following line in the code and it would work.

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).